# Pragmatic methods for debugging mixed C++ and Java code

Tags: java, c++, debugging

I'm developing a wrapper for a C/C++ library in Java, and it's gotten to the point where it is *mostly* working, but there are occasional segfaults and other errors popping up. I'm using Eclipse for development, and it looks like they are working towards mixed debugging, but it is not finished yet.

Can anyone suggest good techniques, best practises for this kind of debugging, beyond debugging the C++ and Java separately or adding lots of print statements?

**EDIT** just in case it is relevant - I'm not developing for Android, so any Android specific tools will not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not found anything but using print statements for the Java
side, but it's quite possible to attach gdb to the Java process,
or start the JVM under gdb, and set break points, examine
variables, etc. with it.

Comment: Could you point to some instructions for doing this? Everything I'm trying results in a hung process.

Comment: Do you mean, on the net, or in some documentation? Not really.  I had to experiment (aka making stabs in the dark) a bit myself to get it to work.  However, if you compile your .so (this is under Linux) with `-ggdb` and no optimization, you arrange to pause the Java program before loading the libraries, and you start `gdb` in the same directory as you started Java, connecting it to the JVM process, it seems to work: at least, I've been able to set breakpoionts and look at C++ variables in the .so.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm on OSX, and it took a lot of struggling to get gdb to debug java happily. In the end I went with Mariot Chauvin's plugin, which despite being 3 years old and unmaintained seems to work OK (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Support_seamless_debugging_between_JDT_and_CDT)